# How do I select 3 columns and then drop duplicates from only two of the selected columns?

Tags: sql

I'm working with a table that contains 3 columns, all columns have integer datatypes.

I'm trying to replicate the following PySpark code into SQl

```
df = my_table.select('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3')
df = df.drop_duplicates(['column_1', 'column_2'])
```

In the above code I'm trying to select three columns and then drop duplicates from only the first two.

I tried using

```
SELECT 
MIN(column_1), MIN(column_2), column_3

FROM my_table

GROUP BY column_3
```

and it looks like it did get the job done but the output wasn't similar to the PySpark output.

Please Advise.

*Note: I'm actually writing this query on dbt so I can't specify a SQL version*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to drop duplicates from both `col1` and `col2` using `ROW_NUMBER()` in the following query:

```
        SELECT col1, col2, col3
        FROM
        (
        SELECT
        col1, col2, col3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS row_num
        FROM table_name
        )
        WHERE row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with that.

```
SELECT mt1.MIN(col1) as min1, mt2.MIN(col2) as min2, mt1.col3
FROM my_table as mt1 
JOIN my_table as mt2 on mt1.id = mt2.id
WHERE min1 != min2
GROUP BY col3;
```

Comment: `\nAggregate/Window/Generate expressions are not valid in where clause of the query`

Comment: I have edited my first proposition...

Comment: Which column is `id`

Comment: You haven't an identify id for each row ?